# creating an object with a Constructor vs a Closure

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, closures

**QUESTION:** Is there any difference in the resulting object `obj` of the two examples below?

**Closure example:**

```
var myClosure = function(paramId) {
  return {
    Id : paramId,
    getId : function() {console.log(this.Id)},
    setId : function(sId) {this.Id = sId}
  };
}
var obj = myClosure(2);
obj.getId();//outputs 2
obj.setId(5);
obj.getId();//outputs 5
```

**Constructor example:**

```
var MyConstr = function(Id) 
{
  this.Id = Id;
  this.getId = function() { console.log(this.Id)};
  this.setId = function(sId) {this.Id = sId};
}
var obj = new MyConstr(2);
obj.getId();//outputs 2
obj.setId(5);
obj.getId();//outputs 5
```

I understand that it is best practice to use a Constructor to create objects, since that is its essential purpose, and would confuse future code readers less. My questions purpose here is out of curiosity. Is there some sort of a difference in the end result? Be it with the object, or the memory usage, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Both object will have the same own properties and methods. However, the one constructed with `new MyConstr` will have its [[proto]] referencing MyConstr.prototype, allowing it to inherit methods and properties.

You're not using those features so it makes no difference in your case, but you should actually define `setId` and `getId` on the prototype, which would save memory (no more copying the methods on each instance) and a little time (the constructor would do less work).

Additionally, constructing an instance will allow you to use the `instanceof` operator.

Answer (score 1):

In this example there are no differences, but you could fine different usage in real world application.

The closure example is usually used for [The Module Pattern][1] or [The Revealing Module Pattern][2].

The constructor example is usually used for the [The Constructor Pattern][3] and [The Prototype Pattern][4] pattern.

In your case I would suggest using the The Prototype Pattern as currently you are adding `getId` and `setId` function to each new object created, when instead you could save some memory adding to the prototype.

Also you should consider using JavaScript getter and setter for instead of `getId` and `setId`.